# How to get Id as key and String as value in multiselect drop down while using Spring and ajax with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I want to get the result as key as `subtestId` and value as `subestName`. I want to see only name in multiselect box.

I am getting result as JSON as like below:

```
{  
   "subtestId":1,
   "testId":2,
   "subtestCode":"STC-1",
   "subtestName":"SUBTEST 1",
   "price":1000,
   "testName":null
},
{  
   "subtestId":2,
   "testId":2,
   "subtestCode":"STC-2",
   "subtestName":"SUBTEST 2",
   "price":2000,
   "testName":null
},
{  
   "subtestId":3,
   "testId":2,
   "subtestCode":"STC-3",
   "subtestName":"SUBTEST 3",
   "price":3000,
   "testName":null
}
```

If you observe the result which is above I am getting key as `subtestId` and value as `1`, key as `testId` and value as `2` etc.

I want it as key as `1` and value as `SUBTEST-1`.

My code follows

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTestId", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String ajaxSubtestList(@RequestParam("reqtestId") int reqtestId) {
        String jsonObj = null;
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List ls = mainDao.listOfSubTestsAjaxReq(reqtestId);
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < ls.size(); i++) {
                jsonObj = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ls);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("jsonObj ==== " + jsonObj);
        return jsonObj;
    }
```

JSP:

```
<div class="form-group">
                                  <label>Test</label>
                                  <form:select path="testId" items="${testsList}" itemValue="testId" itemLabel="testName" value="${billPayment.testId}" id="ajaxTestId" class="form-control" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <label>SubTests</label>
                                  <form:select multiple="true" name="subTestId" path="subTestId" class="form-control" id="ajaxSubTestId" itemLabel="subtestId" itemValue="subtestName">
                                    <c:forEach var="prof" items="">
                                        <form:option value="${prof.key}" label="${prof.value}"/>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                  </form:select>
                                </div>  


$('#ajaxTestId').change(function(){
          var reqtestId = $('#ajaxTestId').val();
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              //contentType: 'application/json',
              url: "getTestId.html",
              data: "reqtestId=" + reqtestId,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(response){
                  $.each(response, function(i, data) {
                    alert("subteset Id is ==== "+JSON.stringify(response));
                    populateData(data,'#ajaxSubTestId');

                  });
              },
              error: function(e){
                alert('Error: '+ JSON.stringify(e));
              }
          });
        });
       function populateData(data,elementId){
           $(elementId+' option').remove();
           var options; //"<option value='-1'>All</option>";
           $.each(data, function(key, value) {
           options += "<option value="+key+">"+value+"</option>";
           });
           //alert('Options === '+options)
           $(elementId).append(options);           
        }
```

Comment: It looks you have unnecessary each loop in success method. can you share your response in success method.

Comment: Hi Manoj Yadav I am gettin response as
{  
   "subtestId":1,
   "testId":2,
   "subtestCode":"STC-1",
   "subtestName":"SUBTEST 1",
   "price":1000,
   "testName":null
}

Comment: you have shared only one object. I suspect it to an array of objects with your original question's json.